# How can I explore and/or modify Apache httpd's DAVLock file?

Tags: apache2, webdav, berkeleydb, webdavfs

I have an Apache httpd server running `mod_dav` (and `mod_dav_fs`) and I have what appear to be stale locks on files that I'd like to manually expire.

I can see the `DAVLock` file on the disk, and the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dav_fs.html#davlockdb) says that the file is an [SDBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm) file, but I haven't managed to find any tools that can read the file.

I'm running on Debian Linux. The `file` utility tells me that this file is a `Berkeley DB (Hash, version 9, native byte-order)` file.

I don't mind writing my own utility as long as I get some pointers as to how to read/write these files. Any ideas?